# Want shortcut to OpenVPN GUI connect in Windows 7 (without going through the system tray)

Tags: windows-7, openvpn

I am running OpenVPN with OpenVPN GUI under Windows 7 x64.  Currently, to connect I need to right-click the OpenVPN icon in the system tray and select "connect", which brings up the password prompt.  What I want: some sort of a batch file or a shortcut that can be invoked to initiate OpenVPN connection.

Motivation: I prefer running my system keyboard driven; I usually hide my taskbar and don't like needlessly fishing in the system tray.  Currently, OpenVPN is the only program that forces me to interact with the taskbar.  Surely there is an alternative approach, possibly invoking some command line trickery and/or autohotkey, but so far I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the VPN with a command.

```
net start openvpnservice
```

Comment: This does not work with an encrypted private key.  Still, marking as accepted b/c with a decrypted key it works fine.

Comment: Start the service as per Eric's post, and then launch OpenVPN GUI with a profile:

  "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --connect myconfig.ovpn

Comment: How can I automatize the user/password prompt?  I already have a xxx.ovpn file from a public VPN server.